# understanding IVT vs MVT

Tags: calculus

I know that if the MVT was applied to physics then it would roughly translate to saying that the average velocity = instantaneous velocity.

But suppose that my average velocity on $[0,T]$ was $10$. Then  $\frac{f(T)-f(0)}{T-0}=10.$ Assuming that $\int f' \,dt = f$, then $\frac{f(T)-f(0)}{T-0} = \frac{\int^{T}_{0} f' \,dt}{T}=10.$

In other words, the average value of $f'(t)$ is $10$ on $[0,T]$. Intuitively, since $f'(t)$ is continuous, if we interpret it as a continuous velocity function, then $f'(t)$ has to take values greater than 10 and less than 10. But then I can apply the IVT to say that $\exists \, c$ s.t. $f'(c)=10$, i.e. instantaneous velocity at $c$ is 10 or the average velocity...

This confuses me because it appears that the MVT and IVT can be both applied to solve this. any thoughts?

Comment: That is correct. If $f'(t)$ is continuous, then you can apply the IVT as you do. Lots of books don't require this hypothesis for the MVT, though. All you need for the MVT is $f$ continuous on $[0,T]$ and differentiable on $(0,T)$. It is possible that $f'$ is not continuous on $(0,T)$.

Comment: @Matt That looks like it could make a pretty good answer to this question...  :)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this isn't awkward, but following anorton's suggestion I've copied my comment to an answer:

That is correct. If $f′(t)$ is continuous, then you can apply the IVT as you do. Lots of books don't require this hypothesis for the MVT, though. All you need for the MVT is $f$ continuous on $[0,T]$ and differentiable on $(0,T)$. It is possible to apply the MVT even if $f′(t)$ is not continuous on $(0,T)$.